# h2o previous version install error, saying h2o.jar download failed

Tags: r, package, h2o

I have models that depend on version 3.10.0.6 of the R package `h2o`. In a new machine I tried to install from the source file `h2o_3.10.0.6.tar.gz`,

```
install.packages("h2o_3.10.0.6.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

After 10 min, it came back with this complaint,

```
Performing one-time download of h2o.jar from
 http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/h2o/rel-turing/6/Rjar/h2o.jar 
(This could take a few minutes, please be patient...)
Warning in download.file(url = h2o_url, destfile = temp_file, mode = "wb",  :
  downloaded length 60135652 != reported length 62422402
Warning in download.file(url = h2o_url, destfile = temp_file, mode = "wb",  :
  URL 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/h2o/rel-turing/6/Rjar/h2o.jar': status was 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'
Error in download.file(url = h2o_url, destfile = temp_file, mode = "wb",  : 
  download from 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/h2o/rel-turing/6/Rjar/h2o.jar' failed
```

I understand it's an older version and so JVM might have been removed. But could the h2o folks leave the old JVM somewhere so folks like me could still use a previous version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't replicate your error.  I just downloaded the [h2o_3.10.0.6.tar.gz](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/h2o/h2o_3.10.0.6.tar.gz) file from the CRAN archive, and was able to install it properly, so it seems like it must be an internet connectivity issue on your end.  Just did this now:

```
> install.packages("h2o_3.10.0.6.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
* installing *source* package ‘h2o’ ...
** package ‘h2o’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Performing one-time download of h2o.jar from
     http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/h2o/rel-turing/6/Rjar/h2o.jar
(This could take a few minutes, please be patient...)
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (h2o)
```

There are a few other ways to re-install an old version of the **h2o** R package.  If it is a CRAN release version, you can use the **versions** package to install any old version of a CRAN package:

```
install.packages("versions")
install.versions("h2o", versions = "3.10.0.6")
```

Any stable release of H2O can be downloaded from it's release page.  The 3.10.0.6 release page is [here](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turing/6/index.html), and if you click on the "Install in R" tab, it will show you the commands to install that version of H2O from R:

```
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos=(c("https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turing/6/R")))
```

Comment: Your suggestion works. Not sure why mine didn't but problem is solved, thks.